# How to set "Entity has Field" when the Rules Event is unrelated to the entity?

Tags: 8, entities, rules

In [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), I am trying to update/calculate a field in the User's account upon completion of a commerce payment.

The condition data selector obviously only wants to populate commerce related fields, since my Event is "After saving new payment".

How can I define my custom field in the Rules Conditions?

My attempts to set the user or current-user entity has field are unsuccessful. But I know this must be simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to get this to work (whatever your existing Rule looks like ...):

1. Assume your current rule has some actions (= `SomeRulesActions`).
2. Create a new Rules Component like so:

   - Use parameters related to the user (= say `ParmUser`) and  payment (= say `ParmPayment`).
   - Add the Rules Conditions related to your custom field, which you should have available via the `ParmUser`.
   - Add Rules conditions identical to `SomeRulesActions`, using `ParmUser` and/or `ParmPayment`.
   - QA-test your Rules Component using the "Execute" link in front of it (in the Rues UI).
3. Update your existing rule like so:

   - Delete all Rules Actions corresponding to `SomeRulesActions` (their equivalents are now included in the Rules Component you created in the previous step.
   - Add a Rules Action to execute the Rules Component you created in the previous step.

***Easy, no?***

An alternative solution where you don't need an extra Rules Component, is to rework your Rules logic by using the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module. If you wonder how to do that, use [this link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Ps: I'm assuming this is about D7.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, apologies though, this is about D8.  Been at this for 4 days now, stressed beyond belief, ready to pay money for help.  Thought I started to get somewhere when i saw somebody's comment about setting a "Fetch entity by ID" action before setting the "Entity has field" condition.  Did not work.  I have tried likely hundreds of combinations of conditions and actions, and cant get my custom field to appear in the data selector.  The field is a field I added to the User registration form, so I assumed this a child of the User entity, but my assumptions are fruitless.

Comment: "Entity is of Bundle" is the way to expose the fields.